# Invalid hook call when I'm setting values from numpad using useChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

This is my component:

```
const pricePicker = ({
    step,
    precision,
    input,
    placeholder,
    label,
    theme,
    props,
    meta: { touched, error },
    ...rest
}) => {
/*In the FOLLOWING LINES from "function useChange(e)" to "return [value,change]"

is the error known as Invalid hook.
*/

    function useChange(e){
         const [value,setValue] = useState(0);

         function change(event){
             setValue(value => event.target.value);
         }
         return [value,change];
    }

    const handleBlur = (e) => {

        if (e.target.value === '0') e.target.value = '0'

    }


    const handleKeypress = (e)  => {
        const characterCode = e.key
        if (characterCode === 'Backspace') return

        const characterNumber = Number(characterCode)
        if (characterNumber < 0) {
              e.preventDefault()
        }
    }

    const myTheme = {
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        textAlign: 'center',
        header: {
            primaryColor: '#263238',
            secondaryColor: '#f9f9f9',
            highlightColor: '#FFC107',
            backgroundColor: '#607D8B',
        },
        body: {
            primaryColor: '#263238',
            secondaryColor: '#32a5f2',
            highlightColor: '#FFC107',
            backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
        },
        panel: {
            backgroundColor: '#CFD8DC'
        }
    };


    return(
        <div className='form-group'> 

            <label forname={input.name}>{label}</label> <br />
            <NumPad.Number
                {...rest}
                step={0.1}
                precision={2}
                placeholder={!input.value ? 'Please, type a number' : input.value}
                selected={input.value ? new NumPad.Number(input.value) : null}
                onKeyDown={(changedVal) => handleKeypress(changedVal)}
                onBlur={(changedVal) => handleBlur(changedVal)}
                onChange={(changedVal) => useChange(changedVal)}


                className='form-control'


            />
            <div className='text-danger' style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
                {touched && error}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default pricePicker;
```

When I'm executing this block of code:

```
function useChange(e){
    const [value,setValue] = useState(0);
    function change(event){
         setValue(value => event.target.value);
    }
    return [value,change];
}
```

I'm getting the following issue:

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I've tried all ways but it seems it's impossible. I never used hooks and previously I post about something similar but unsuccesfully. Previous post talks about useState is inside `pricePicker` function is neither a funcional component or react hook component when executed previous code lines like this:

```
const handleChange = (e) =>{
     // in the following line is the error.
     const[value, setValue] = useState(0);
}
```

How can I solve this issue? I need to fix it, but how? I've tried all ways but unsuccessfully.

Any one knows how can I fix this issue? It's important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually quite simple - hooks can be used only at the [top level of functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). In your concrete example, you cannot use `useState` inside of function `useChange`.

Instead, do something like:

```
const pricePicker = ({/*props go here*/
    const [value,setValue] = useState(0);
    // handler of input change
    const onChange = e => setValue(e.target.value);

    // the rest of the code can stay the same

   return <div className='form-group'> 
            <label forname={input.name}>{label}</label> <br />
            <NumPad.Number
                {...rest}
                step={0.1}
                precision={2}
                placeholder={!input.value ? 'Please, type a number' : input.value}
                selected={input.value ? new NumPad.Number(input.value) : null}
                onKeyDown={(changedVal) => handleKeypress(changedVal)}
                onBlur={(changedVal) => handleBlur(changedVal)}
                onChange={onChange} /* Here's we use the onChange handler */
                className='form-control'
            />
            <div className='text-danger' style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
                {touched && error}
            </div>
    </div>;
}
```